# Rewriting dynamic urls in nginx config

Tags: php, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, sitemap

I'm working on a PHP app, and I have moved it from apache to nginx server. I have a php page that dynamically creating xml files for sitemap . This works perfectly in apache server but when i moved to nginx its not working .

This is the cde that i'm using in apache

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.xml/?$ sitemap.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the code i used in nginx

```
rewrite "^/([^/]+)\.xml/?$" /sitemap.php?p=$1 last;
```

This is the complete nginx config file. [nginx config file](https://jsfiddle.net/ov0br5mc/1/)

This is what i'm using to create the xml pages dynamically (complete code not included)

```
<?php
require_once( './inc/header.inc.php' );
$connect = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL;
// How many items to list per page
$limit = 10000;

if (!empty($_GET["p"])) { 
    $page = $_GET["p"];

    if ($page === "sitemap_core") {
        // Sitemap Core Page Starts
        echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'.PHP_EOL;

        $core_sitemap_url_arr = array('terms', 'join', 'login', 'blog/', 'about-us', 'sb', 'sm', 'msb');

        foreach ($core_sitemap_url_arr as $url) {
            echo '<url>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo '<loc>'.BX_DOL_URL_ROOT.$url.'</loc>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo '<lastmod>'.date('Y-m-d').'</lastmod>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo '</url>'.PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo '</urlset>'.PHP_EOL;
        // Sitemap Core Page Ends
    }

}
else {
    header("Location:" .BX_DOL_URL_ROOT."404");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your rewrite rule declared in a *.htaccess* file?

Comment: @Lagaart no its in nginx config file

Comment: In the rewrite rule, did you try to remove the first slash? Like this; *"^/([^/]+)\.xml/?$"* ---> *"^([^/]+)\.xml/?$"*

Comment: @soorajspillai I don't see any reason it shouldn't work. Maybe some other directives from nginx rewrite module prevent it from working, but it is hard to say without your full configuration. Where this rule is located, at the `server` or at the `location` context?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Its located under `location` context.

Comment: @soorajspillai Could you try to move it to the `server` context as `rewrite "^/([^/]+)\.xml/?$" /sitemap.php?p=$1;` without the `last` flag?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I've tried the above as you mentioned but still its not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?   Can you post more context from your nginx conf?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller its not working means when i visit sitemap.xml through url its showing "404 not found". Also i'm sharing the full nginx config here. https://jsfiddle.net/ov0br5mc/1/

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've added the details to the question.